# Как настроить сглаживание у шрифта?

Tags: wpf, шрифты

В моём приложении довольно часто используется текст малого размера (12-13 пт) -
 отображение просто ужасное. Какой шрифт и значения TextOptions вы бы посоветовали?

Для сравнения привожу пример моих настроек:

```
SnapsToDevicePixels="True" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="#323232" 
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" 
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
```

и то, как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И отображения Антивируса Касперского (вот такой нужен результат чёткости отображения да и шрифт больше нравится):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приближении (сверху требуемый шрифт):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На увеличенном отчётливо видно, что на первом субпиксельное сглаживание, а на втором обычное. Это так, информация.

Comment: Это вам не у нас, это у дизайнеров спрашивать надо. Если в вашей компании нету дизайнеров, то потребуйте дополнительную зарплату за услуги дизайнера.

Comment: @D-side: Это реализуемо в WPF?

Comment: @VladD: Хорошо))))

Comment: @D-side: Это не тоже с ClearType? Он как раз применяется (согласно представленной разметке) на последней картинке снизу.

Comment: @D-side: Возможно, я использую не тот размер шрифта (Segoe UI)? Кстати говоря, в конструкторе окна WPF шрифт выглядит прекрасно.

Comment: @D.Stark попробуйте поменять ClearType на [что-нибудь другое](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.textrenderingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: Настройки отображения должны спускаться прямо сверху. Если хоть один контрол в дереве с отключенным ClearType или ещё какое чудо случится с настройками отображения текста - ваш ClearType отключится. Перепроверьте с утилитой Snoop всё дерево контролов снизу от вашего до самого верха.

Comment: Нет. ClearType включён. Как для родителей, так и для TextBlock.

Comment: *Проверил в смысле утилитой этой

Comment: @VladD: Настройки здесь особо не причём вообщем то. Ведь WPF использует DirectX, а не GDI/GDI+. За это приходится платить ужасным качеством мелких шрифтов (менее 14 px). Говорят раньше было ещё хуже. Даже не могу предложить что бы здесь намудрить. Вопрос явно не имеет дизайнерского характера, т.к. проблема решается исключительно программно. На данный момент, я пробую подбирать разные шрифты и смотреть их отображение в размерах текста 12-14 px (с шагом 0.1).

Comment: @VladD: При чём в конструкторе Blend текст отображается идеально (есс-но в масштабе 1:1).

Comment: @D.Stark: А проблема воспроизводится на мелкой тестовой программе?

Comment: @Monk: Вообще то я пришёл к выводу что работа со TextOptions ничего не даст. Почитайте мои комментарии выше)

Comment: @D.Stark: И да, проверьте на другой машине, возможно, на этой что-то не так с настройками.

Comment: @VladD: Я попробую прямо сейчас, но весьма сомневаюсь. Как следует я прогуглил эту тему и, вообщем то, у всех есть такие проблемы. С мелкой тестовой программой и работаю.

Comment: @D.Stark: И ещё попробуйте флаги наподобие `UseLayoutRounding` и `SnapsToDevicePixels` (только не забывайте, что их надо выставлять **во всём дереве**).

Comment: В смысле во всём дереве? Это для каждого родителя до окна?

Comment: @VladD: Я вот сейчас всё таки ещё один проект создал и там всё нормально. Видимо (несмотря на то что я и так предыдущий проект только для целей тестов создавал) проблема была в проекте)))

Comment: @VladD: Обойдёмся ClearType и SnapsToDevicePixels.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: @D.Stark: А вот это уже интересно. Может быть, попробовать методом «половинного деления» найти, где же в проекте проблема? Это было бы интересно на будущее.

Comment: @D.Stark: Да, для каждого родителя. UseLayoutRounding означает, что дробные позиции _относительно родителя_ округляются до целых. Но если родитель сам находится на дробной координате, это не поможет.

Comment: @VladD: Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, помочь ещё вот с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683216/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-volatile

Answer (score 2):

Уберите сглаживание:

```
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
```

На ваших фото видно что в желаемом виде его нет.

Comment: Приму поправку. Есть идеи что бы применить для изменения положения?

Comment: Почему же всё таки нет желаемого результата?..