# В каком случае лучше использовать volatile?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Предположим, у меня имеется `List<T>`, который одновременно читает один поток, а другой в него пишет. В данному случае что было бы правильнее и быстрее использовать: volatile или ConcurrentBag?

Comment: На тему [volatile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/) от Eric Lippert

Answer (score 11, accepted):

О скорости можно говорить лишь тогда, когда у вас имплементирована функциональность, и профилирование показывает, что доступ к данным является bottleneck'ом. Поэтому давайте разберёмся с корректностью.

Начнём с того, что `volatile` мы не можем применить к списку — `volatile`-поля могут быть только элементарных типов. Даже если бы его можно было применить, что толку в синхронизации доступа к ссылке на контейнер? Гонки-то у нас по данным внутри контейнера.

`ConcurrentBag` — это более разумный выбор. Но это только если реально данные лишь *добавляются* в одном из потоков, а не *модифицируются* им. В зависимости от вашей точной задачи, может понадобиться `ConcurrentBag` (если не важен порядок) или `ConcurrentQueue` (если важен).

Если нужен доступ по индексу, или модификация данных в пишущем потоке (например: `collection[i]++`), не стоит искать выгоду в несколько микросекунд, проще и безопаснее использовать нормальный `lock`.

Comment: Даст ли выигрыш использование ReadWriterLockSlim вместо lock? Или, опять же, не стоит париться ради пары мс?

Comment: Уточню, что потоков у меня 2 и оба активно как пишу, так и читают. (в вопросе я немного не правильно написал)

Comment: @D.Stark: Нет, выигрыша не даст. Выигрыш мог бы быть, если у вас **несколько** читателей — тогда они могут одновременно читать под read-блокировкой. В ситуации, когда читатель один, наоборот, получается проигрыш: `lock` всё же дешевле.

Comment: @D.Stark: В качестве оптимизации можно будет (потом) подумать о том, чтобы блокировать кусками, например. Но это сильно зависит от того, как именно у вас «двигаются» данные.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Останавливаемся на lock.

Comment: В комментариях ответа ниже был вопрос по поводу различий асинхронности и многопоточности.

Comment: А как же в том случае если код (который мы запускаем в задаче) работает с некоторыми переменными? Т.е. у нас есть основной поток, в котором есть переменная, и мы запустим несколько задач, которые с этой переменной работают (вместе с основным потоком читают и модифицируют её). В многопоточном программировании надо заботиться о таких вещах (например, использовать блокировку lock). Следует ли заботиться об аналогичных ситуациях в задачах? Я так понимаю, что нет. Значит, об этих вещах заботится TaskScheduler?

Comment: @D.Stark: Если переменная локальная, то заботиться не нужно, `await` действует как барьер. А если у вас общая переменная (разделяемое между потоками поле или переменная в замыкании), то `lock` снова-таки нужен, насколько я понимаю, потому что в этом случае несколько тасков могут обращаться к ней одновременно.

Comment: А если у меня задача работает с общей переменной вместе с основным потоком? Они оба постоянно её читают и модифицируют. Нужен ли тут lock?

Comment: @D.Stark: Да, если у вас с одной переменной работают несколько потоков одновременно, `lock` необходим. Но если вы так делаете, есть шанс, что вы делаете неправильно. Попробуйте делать так, чтобы таск работал только с локальными переменными, и сообщал результат через `return`.

Comment: Мой асинхронный метод работает с членами класса. Результат возвращает через return. Я сейчас просто говорю о наличии в классе 2ух версий метода: синхронной и асинхронной, и надо ли заботиться о работе асинхронной версии (которая просто запускает синхронный метод в задаче, т.е. никакой разницы в коде).

Comment: Выглядит это так: https://pastebin.com/HQNPqHJu

Comment: *Пользователь может изменить Val во время работы AsyncMethod

Comment: @D.Stark: Смотрите. Если с переменной работают из разных потоков — нужна синхронизация. Это основное правило. Если ваш таск всё время выполняется в UI-потоке, то проблем нет, у вас один поток, и вы можете пользоваться полями. Если таск меняет свои потоки, но пользуется локальными переменными, проблем тоже нет. А если таск меняет свои потоки и пользуется «чужими» переменными, тогда нужна синхронизация. Всё очень просто.

Comment: Хорошо. Мой Task работает в основном потоке. Вывод: синхронизация не нужна.

Comment: @D.Stark: Так что правильно или нет, зависит от того, что именно происходит в `AsyncMethod` и запускаете ли вы его в UI-потоке или нет. Универсального правила раз и навсегда, чтобы не думать, нет и быть не может.

Comment: @D.Stark: да, **если** таск работает в UI-потоке, то многопоточного доступа просто нет, и синхронизация не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно.